# how to create a Google sign out class file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

class file easily access to every page in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially set it zero

```
lastFirstVisiblePosition = 0;
```

You can store a scroll position on the scroll and set a scroll position like this.

```
((LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(lastFirstVisiblePosition);
```

and if that not work try below

```
((LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(lastFirstVisiblePosition,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to save instance manually, just make sure that all views has an unique id in xml layout and android will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

At the time you add new elements in adapter's list use this method to notify you adapter. it will retain the current position and add all new elements below the last item.

Answer (score 0):

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 will notify your entire list ,which will make your list to scroll to top position so use 
 **notifyItemChanged(int position)** which will update only that position 
and if you want to notify some range then use  **notifyItemRangeChanged(position,size)**
  for details refer this link for more detail. [RecyclerView.Adapter to notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

Override onAttachedToRecyclerView to get the RecyclerView reference in your adaptor class

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }
```

Override onViewRecycled to get the lastVisiblePosition which you can use when you will again reload your recycler view

```
@Override
    public void onViewRecycled(SiteHolder viewHolder) {
        lastVisiblePosition  = ((GridLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

    }
```

Where ever you are doing your reloading of data(as a setter of Arraylist or whatever way)
first call

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and then

```
((GridLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(lastVisiblePosition);
```

This will make sure data reload to happen first then scrolling

Comment: Bro adding full code will need your full code then only I can add my changes wherever it is required

Comment: sorry sir thanks for reply update my code please add your your changes.